# ActiveMQ - Java process stay alive when I want to stop it

Tags: java, multithreading, process, activemq-classic, shutdown

I have a java process which connects to ActiveMQ (as consumer). It causes problems when I'm trying to stop it cleanly.

The process is stopping as follow:

- A control message is received, asking for the process to stop
- The consumers, sessions & connection are closed, waiting for all messages already received to be processed
- final log message is printed
- Process shutdown & doesn't exist anymore

The process seems to shutdown okay if it didn't process any message yet. But once a message has been received, the process doesn't stop, and I'm not sure why (the final log message is printed)

I've printed a thread dump to see what was going on, but I'm not sure what could cause the issue:

```
Attaching to process ID 17264, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.201-b09
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 20: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=59 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.java2d.Disposer.run() @bci=3 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 19: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 18: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=78 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=124 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 17: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.run() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 1: (state = BLOCKED)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 10: (state = BLOCKED)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 9: (state = BLOCKED)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 8: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=59 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=36 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 7: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(boolean) @bci=54 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
   - None
```

From what I see,

- Thread 8/20 is garbage collector waiting to collect something
- Thread 7 is linked to garbage collector as well
- Thread 18/19 ???
- Thread 17 is a Timer instance, not sure who started it

**ActiveMQ version:** 5.15.4

**ActiveMQConnectionFactory url:** failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?timeout=3000&maxReconnectAttempts=10

No other specific parameters

Comment: The reason might be the scoket connection might be still alive. Try to use netstat command to find it.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? What URL is your consumer using to connect? Are you setting any special parameters?